# Extracting text using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Below is an excerpt of the html code:

```
<div class="Class1">Category1</div>
<div class="Class2">"Text1 I want"</div>
<div class="Class1">Category2</div>
<div class="Class2">"Text2 I want"</div>
```

I know I can extract Text1 and Text2 by using:

```
find_element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='Class2']")
element = [x.text for x in find_element]
text1 = element[0]
text2 = element[1]
```

But if the structure of the html is changed, elements will be changed accordingly. Is there any way for me to extract Text1 and Text2 by referring to Category1 and Category2, respectively?

Thank you.

Comment: Please give some examples of structure changes, we need to know which part is immutable  among the structure change examples to see figure out how we can use the immutable part to archive your goal.  Or you can directly tell us the immutable parts,  like class name of `Categoryx`, class name of  `Text I want` etc.

Comment: @yong I don't know if the structure is going to change, just trying to avoid potential errors to extract the texts by referring to their categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Text I want` always inside the next sibling `div` of `Category div`, you can try as following:

**Case 1**

```
<div class="Class1">Category1</div>
<div class="Class2">"Text1 I want"</div>
```

`//div[.='Category1']/following-sibling::div[1]`

**Case 2**

```
<div class="Class1">Category1</div>
<div class="Class2">
  <div class="xxx">
    <span>"Text1 I want"</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

`//div[.='Category1']/following-sibling::div[1]//span`

There can be many possible structure, the key part in the xpath is `//div[.='Category1']/following-sibling::div[1]`

Comment: Thank you. That's all I need.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using BeautifulSoup. Find the Category1 tag, then its `next_sibling`:

```
import bs4
your_html = browser.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(your_html, 'lxml')

class1tag = soup.find('div', text='Category1')
tag = class1tag.next_sibling.next_sibling
print(tag)
#<div class="Class2">"Text1 I want"</div>
print(tag.text)
#"Text1 I want"
```

Comment: I tried. And the website prohibited me from extracting info using BeautifulSoup.

Comment: If you can open it with selenium, you can save the document as HTML: `html = browser.page_source`.

Comment: That would be too much though, as I'll be saving at least 3,000 html. I'll try it out, but is there other more efficient way to do so?

Comment: I do not understand your concern. You still have to parse all the HTML documents to get the data that you want.

Comment: I was just thinking to avoid downloading too many files (HTML documents in this case) because extract those few texts was all I need.

Comment: You do understand that by opening them in the browser you _already_ have downloaded them?

Comment: True, as the cache. I'll try your method out anyway to see if it's more efficient. To be honest, I don't want to use selenium because it's too slow compared to beautifulsoup

Comment: Selenium is not a replacement for BS, it is a replacement for urllib and the like. BS is used not for downloading but for parsing.

Comment: Right, and ironically, I'm now parsing the data through selenium because bs cannot parse data from that website

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your concern regarding changes to the structure of the html are based on the fact that the semantics of the data is of key- value paid (the keys being the categories and the values are the text), while the structure is simply a list of divs where the odd ones are the keys and the following even ones are their corresponding values.
The problem though isn't with your Selenium locators, but rather in the structure of the html itself (which consequently affects your ability to use more robust locators). I would suggest that you ask the developers to improve the structure of the html to reflect it's appropriate semantics. Discuss *together* the best structure that fits all the needs, including those of the test automation.